# If variable equals the number 1

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to write a very simple if statement in my jquery.  If the variable equals the number one then do this, if it equals the number two then do this.  This is what I wrote but it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why:

```
$("#next-btn").click(function() {
    if (current_slide = 1) {
        first_screen();
    }, else if (current_slide = 2) {
        second_screen();
    } 
});
```

probably very simple, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: `current_slide == 1`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 13):

You need to use [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `==` in [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) condition instead of assignment operator `=` also remove `comma` after first closing curly bracket of `then` (true) block of `if` statement. You can test it over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptyzz/).

```
if (current_slide == 1) {
      first_screen();
} else if (current_slide == 2) {
      second_screen();
}
```

I assume current_slide has some number to compare, you read below how comparison operator == performs the comparison.

#### Comparion equal operator

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number
>   or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else
>   if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a
>   string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript
>   compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to
>   the same object in memory, [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: There are other things to fix.

Comment: You might want to suggest removing the comma before the else and changing current_slide = 2 to current_slide == 2

Comment: yes!  Very simple, thanks for the explanation, always nice when someone uses vocab in a clear way.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, your eyes are very quick to catch errors / flaws:).

Answer (score 3):

Use comparison operator "==" instead of assignment "=" and remove comma before `else if`.

```
$("#next-btn").click(function() {
    if (current_slide == 1) {
        first_screen();
    }else if (current_slide == 2) {
        second_screen();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it'd be better using switch:

```
$("#next-btn").click(function() {
    switch(current_slide) {
        case 1:
            first_screen();
            break;
        case 2:
            second_screen();
            break;            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Youd shouldn´t check a condition with an assigment:

```
$("#next-btn").click(function() {
    if(current_slide===1){
        first_screen();
    }else if (current_slide===2){
        second_screen();
    } 
});
```